# hi-lock for changing face of comments with font-lock enabled

Tags: hi-lock

I want to change the face of specific patterns in the comments or `emacs-lisp (.el)` files.  The face of comments already use `font-lock` when in `emacs-lisp-mode`.

I want to change some particular types of comments to look like headings.

For instance, getting text enclosed in square brackets to show as `blue`, rather than `green` as for normal comments.

```
;; [heading]
;; Some comment
;; One more comment
```

Is using `hi-lock` the proper way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `add-font-lock-keywords` and the variable `font-lock-keywords` for how to do this. The if you have `prepend` in the OVERRIDE field, your new face will be seen on top of the normal comment face.

Comment: Will the new face apply to all comments or only to those matching `;; [heading]` ?

Comment: How does the `add-font-lock-keywords` solution compare to `hi-lock` solution?

Comment: "The proper way", "the best way", etc. encourage opinion-based answers. Please ask a simple, specific how-to question.

Comment: Naturally I expect explanations and situations for appropriateness. Why would one prefer using `add-font-lock-keywords` rather than `hi-lock` ?

Comment: `hi-lock` is written on top of `font-lock-add-keywords`. It's mainly intended for simple regexp:s, but I'm not sure it has access to all the details you have when calling `font-lock-add-keywords` directly.

Comment: In summary `hi-lock` is still basically `font-lock`.  Can one say that: 1) for simple `regexp` one could use `hi-lock`; 2) and for more complicated ones, use `add-font-lock-keywords`.  It occurs to me that `add-font-lock-keywords` is a bit more complicated to use.